# How to delete Label Resources and change defaut menu in Laravel Nova?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I would like to change the default menu of Nova to have a grouped menu but that we unfold if necessary. I also want to remove the word Resources. any help ! Thank you in advance.

**Here is what i have:**

[image]

**I want to have something like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nova has a [navigation.blade.php](https://github.com/laravel/nova/blob/3.0/resources/views/resources/navigation.blade.php) file that renders the sidebar resources.

To override blade views you can copy the file to `resources/views/vendor/nova` folder.
To make it easier,you can use the following commands to make the directory and copy the file from vendor folder.

```sh
mkdir -p resources/views/vendor/nova/resources/
cp -r vendor/laravel/nova/resources/views/resources/navigation.blade.php resources/views/vendor/nova/resources/navigation.blade.php
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer @Rosin